# String match and assign tag accordingly

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to have a new_column in the data frame which says the indicator 'LH 'or 'RH'. I have tried the below code on the additional_info column.

```
LH = ['lhd','lh','lhd','left','le']
RH = [ 'rhd','rh','rhd','right,'re']
lh_rh= match_id[['MATA_info','tech_info','additional_info']]
lh_rh['additional_info']= lh_rh['additional_info'].str.lower()
Right = lh_rh.loc[lh_rh['additional_info'].isin(RH)]
left = lh_rh.loc[lh_rh['additional_info'].isin(LH)]
```

I would like to match if the keywords in LH and RH matches either with the columns 'MATA_info','tech_info',and 'additional_info' then additional column with the name 'Relation' should be created and assign value to LH or RH accordingly.

```
   MATA_info  tech_info   additional_info  Relation
3,50X085Right    F85        NAN              RH
3,50X085Left     F85        lh               LH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), then check if at least one `True` per rows by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), last pass it to [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
LH = ['lhd','lh','lhd','left','le']
RH = [ 'rhd','rh','rhd','right','re']
lh_rh= match_id[['MATA_info','tech_info','additional_info']]
m1 = lh_rh.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('|'.join(LH), na=False, case=False)).any(axis=1)
m2 = lh_rh.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('|'.join(RH), na=False, case=False)).any(axis=1)

match_id['Relation'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['LH','RH'], default=np.nan)

print (match_id)
       MATA_info tech_info additional_info Relation
0  3,50X085Right       F85             NAN       RH
1   3,50X085Left       F85              lh       LH
2           4,56        %T              jj      nan
```

EDIT:

```
pat1 = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in LH)
pat2 = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in RH)
m1 = lh_rh.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(pat1, na=False, case=False)).any(axis=1)
m2 = lh_rh.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(pat2, na=False, case=False)).any(axis=1)
```

Comment: this works perfectly well, but I have little issue with it.
when there is a string in MATA_info such as 'length' then it also tags as LH in Relation column (because length contains 'le').

Comment: @Rocky - yes, but it is complicated, because  how distinguish `3,50X085Left` with `3,50X085le` ? Or there are in real data spaces like `3,50X085 Left` and `3,50X085 le` arounf words from lists?

Comment: for example this text in mata_info column "575X17,00XCLIP" it tagged as LH because clip contained 'li'. Is there any way that it matches the complete word not a substring?

Comment: and yes, there are spaces around the words